# sed gives “illegal byte sequence” error when trying to replace a character

Tags: macos, terminal, sed, osx-yosemite

I am using the “Terminal” in Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) and I am trying to delete all occurrences of `a` from a file, by using `sed`:

```
sed 's/a//g' file
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence
```

`sed 's/a//' file` works without a problem. The error appears when I add the `g` modifier to the regular expression.

Comment: [RE error: illegal byte sequence on Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19242275)

Comment: Does it mean that the encoding of the file is different?

Comment: [Getting "sed error - illegal byte sequence" (in bash)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11287564)

Answer (score -1):

You need to add -i along with two empty ''. So it would look like this:
`sed -i '' 's/a//g' filename.txt`

Explanation is that -i equals in-place (save it right back to the original file)

Comment: While sed -i does require an argument on OS X and BSD but not on Linux, this is not the problem.